# Systemd unable to run bluetooth target?

Tags: debian, bluetooth, systemd

When I startup my system (Debian OS), and the systemd reach the target Bluetooth, it takes **1min30s** before telling me that dependency failed for disk_by_device and for swap.

Please how can deactivate bluetooth definitely ?

```
iamatacos@debian1:~ $ sudo journalctl -u bluetooth
-- Logs begin at Sun 2017-09-17 18:10:44 WEST, end at Sun 2017-09-17 18:20:44 WEST. --
sept. 17 18:12:16 debian1 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
sept. 17 18:12:18 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Bluetooth daemon 5.45
sept. 17 18:12:19 debian1 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
sept. 17 18:12:19 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Starting SDP server
sept. 17 18:12:20 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
sept. 17 18:12:21 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Sap driver initialization failed.
sept. 17 18:12:21 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
sept. 17 18:12:33 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
sept. 17 18:12:33 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
sept. 17 18:12:57 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
sept. 17 18:12:57 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
sept. 17 18:12:57 debian1 bluetoothd[792]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try stopping and disabling the bluetooth service:

`sudo systemctl stop bluetooth 
 sudo systemctl disable bluetooth`

Comment: I have got this : bluetoothd[772]: Stopping SDP server
 bluetoothd[772]: Exit
 systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.

Comment: did not fix it :(

Comment: Do you have rfkill installed? You can use use that to soft block the bluetooth device: run "rfkill list" to get the device identifier then a simple "rfkill block IDENTIFIER" should do the trick. If you don't have it installed "sudo apt-get install rfkill"

Comment: already done it, but still 1: **hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no**

Comment: I am unable to disable definitely bluetooth , strange